# Crear lista a partir de array en el que cada valor se sustituye por su orden de aparición al ordenar los valores únicos del array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ordenamiento

Tengo un array grande de números tipo float y quiero crear otro donde; el número más pequeño del primero sea un cero en el otro y a partir de aquí, los siguientes en orden ascendente se les vaya sumando 1 y creando el otro array, sin ordenar el array de números originales.

Estoy intentando esto:

```
def embeding(vector):
  new_vector = []
  cont = 0
  for p, num in enumerate(vector):
    if num == np.min(vector):
      new_vector.append(cont)
      np.delete(num, p)
    cont +=1
  return new_vector
```

Pero cuando ejecuto la función me da este error:

> ```
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-41-1731b2434157> in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 embeding(signal_sample)
>
> 2 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in delete(arr, obj, axis)
>    5154         # optimization for a single value
>    5155         if (obj < -N or obj >= N):
> -> 5156             raise IndexError(
>    5157                 "index %i is out of bounds for axis %i with "
>    5158                 "size %i" % (obj, axis, N))
>
> IndexError: index 22555 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
> ```

Si alguien me puede echar una mano se agradece, saludos!

Comment: Estas pasando a `np.delete` `num` como primer argumento, que es un float (`numpy.float64` seguramente), en esencia estas intentando indizar sobre un float... Si quieres eliminar ese item del array, deberia ser  `np.delete(vector, p)` pero de cualquier forma **jamas se te ocurra eliminar o agregar  items a un iterable al mismo tiempo que iteras con un  `for ` sobre el, eso invalida el iterador y tendras resultados "curiosos"....

Comment: Aparte de eso, y teniendo en cuenta que [comparar floats no es tan simple como parece](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/)  ¿cual seria la salida esperada para `[1.2, 4.3, 0.5, 2.3, 1.2, 0.5, 7.3]` por ejemplo?

Comment: Vale, tomo nota de lo primero y si efectivamente la salida seria una lista pero con num entre 0 y 1.

Comment: Para el ejemplo que pongo en el comentario de arriba (`np.array([1.2, 4.3, 0.5, 2.3, 1.2, 0.5, 7.3])`) ¿la salida esperada seria exactamente `[1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 4]`? ¿O tu array no tiene duplicados?

Comment: Si seria la salida esperada, y si hay repetidos.  Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Probando esto:

```
def embeding(vector):
  new_vector = []
  cont = 0
  for p, num in enumerate(vector):
    if num == np.min(vector):
      pos_del = p
      np.append(new_vector, cont)
    cont +=1
  np.delete(vector, pos_del)
  return new_vector
```

con el delete fuera del bucle me debe eliminar todo por que me devuelve una lista vacia.

Answer (score 0):

Hay múltiples problemas con tu aproximación:

- El error en si esta causado porque llamas a numpy.delete asi:

  ```
    np.delete(num, p)
  ```

  donde `num` es un item de `vector` (un float) y `p` su indice, en todo caso deberías llamarla así:

  ```
    vector = np.delete(vector, p)
  ```

  observa que se asigna la salida de `np.delete` a vector, `np.delete` no actúa in-place, retorna un nuevo array. Dicho esto: **jamas hagas esta mostruosidad**. Me refiero a que **nunca debes eliminar o agregar items de cualquier iterable mientras iteras sobre el con un ciclo `for`**, hacer esto invalida automáticamente el iterador del ciclo y causa resultados y errores inesperados.
- Por otro lado, no puedes simplemente usar `list.append`, tienes que asignar `cont` en las posiciones/indices en las que el valor mínimo esta en vector.
- Un solo ciclo no te basta, necesitas dos. Por cada valor mínimo tienes que recorrer el vector en su totalidad para ver en que posiciones esta ese valor y asignar `cont` en esas misma posiciones a la lista de salida.

Para que tu idea funcione, debieras hacer algo como esto (se asume que `vector` es un `numpy.array` de floats unidimensional.):

```
import numpy as np

def embeding(vector):
    new_vector = [None] * vector.size
    vector_cop = vector.copy()
    count = 0
    while vector_cop.size:
        min_value = np.min(vector_cop)
        for p, num in enumerate(vector):
            if num == min_value:
                new_vector[p] = count
        count += 1
        vector_cop = vector_cop[vector_cop != min_value] # Eliminar todas las apariciones del valor mínimo
    return new_vector
```

El problema es que esto es horriblemente ineficiente tanto en términos de procesamiento como de espacio (memoria), recorremos el vector al completo y generamos un nuevo vector_copia por cada valor único del vector original, por no mencionar el uso de `numpy.min` en cada iteración...

Una opción mucho mas simple y eficiente que se me ocurre es usar un diccionario y `numpy.unique` que retorna una copia del array con los valores únicos y ordenados, hecho esto basta una sola iteración sobre el vector para generar la lista de salida:

```
import numpy as np

def embeding(vector):
    map_values = {value: count for count, value in enumerate(np.unique(vector))}
    return [map_values[value] for value in vector]
```

> ```
> >>> arr = np.array([1.2, 4.3, 0.5, 2.3, 1.2, 0.5, 7.3])
> >>> embeding(arr)
> [1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 4]
> ```

Comment: Como puedes ver en la salida de ejemplo al final de la respuesta cada valor esta en la posición que le corresponde al item en el vector original no ordenado, el orden del vector de entrada y el de la lista de salida no se alteran ni se ordenan en ningún momento.

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido de mucho para aprender más sobre bucles.